# Turning a RestReponse into a List<object>

Tags: c#, list, api, split, restsharp

I am using `.GetAsync()` on an [ITAD API endpoint](https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v01/game/map/?key=46594d518d6e4aedb823ecb4e6d00a54a10f1155&shop=steam) then using `.Content` for its string form, but I need a `List<string>` of the titles.

Is there an inbuilt way of turning a RestResponse into a list?
Is there a way to remove everything between and including the text between the titles of the apps to `String.Split` what's left?

[The documentation](https://itad.docs.apiary.io/#reference/game/get-idplain-map/get-map) only shows a way to get the entire response as one object.

Comment: What do you mean by removing everything between and including the text between titles?

Comment: The response in the link lists a lot of data in text, I only need the titles. Is there a way to String.Trim within a range so that I can elimnate, for example, everything between "app: and ":.

Answer (score 1):

Deserialization is your friend here :)

The response data looks like a dictionary, so first define a class to deserialize it into...

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> data { get; set; }
}
```

Add the following `using` to the top of the file where you want to do the deserialization...

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

Assuming you have the string content in a variable named `content`, then deserialize like so...

```
var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(content);
```

Putting it all together using your endpoint & converting the dictionary keys into a list...

```
const string url = @"https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v01/game/map/?key=46594d518d6e4aedb823ecb4e6d00a54a10f1155&shop=steam";
var client = new RestClient();
var restRequest = new RestRequest(url);
var restResponse = client.GetAsync(restRequest);
var content = restResponse.Result.Content;
var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(content);
var titleIds = response.data.Keys.ToList();
foreach (var id in titleIds)
    Console.WriteLine($"{id}: {string.Join(',', response.data[id])}");
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand deserialization and can't get it to work when the response is all one object rather than a list. All I end up with is a string.

Comment: Deserialization is the fancy name for what you are asking to do ;) I've added a more complete code sample. It works for me. If you want to give it a go & still can't get it working, feel free to let me know the error or how it is not working.